# Removing the prepended directories from $1 variable in a rewrite rule

Tags: iis, rewrite

I have this rewrite rule

`RedirectRule ^(/arf/sites/.*)$ /docs/saf/files$1 [R=301,I,L]`

When it redirects, `$1` contains `/arf/sites/filename.html` so after the redirect, the visitor ends up at

`http://domain.com/docs/saf/files/arf/sites/help/filename.html`

when I was expecting them to end up at

`http://domain.com/docs/saf/files/filename.html`

How do I get rid of the prepended directories in `$1` - or am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the rule to

```
RedirectRule ^/arf/sites/(.*)$ /docs/saf/files$1 [R=301,I,L]
```

should solve the problem.

Comment: Why did that fix the issue? Is $1 filled with whatever you have in () ?

Comment: That's correct. You can even have multiple () which lead to $2, $3 and so on.